# How to list all row of sql?

Tags: php

Hy!

I want to list all row of my table, but it is not works :(

My function.php:

```
function getCharacterAdminJails($account_id) {
    global $connection;
    $stmt = $connection->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM adminjails WHERE jailed_accountID = :account_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":account_id", $account_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $adminjail_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $adminjail_data;
}
```

My example.php, where I list my rows:

```
<table class="table table-hover">   
        <tr>        
            <th>Admin neve:</th>    
            <th>Indok:</th>     
            <th>Perc:</th>      
            <th>Időpont:</th>   
        </tr>       
        <tr>        
            <th><?=$adminjail_data["jailed_admin"];?></th>      
            <th><?=$adminjail_data["jailed_reason"];?></th>
            <th><?=$adminjail_data["jailed_ido"];?></th>
            <th><?=$adminjail_data["jailed_idopont"];?></th>

        </tr>           
    </table>
```

How can I list all rows of my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you change this line of code in your php function from

```
$adminjail_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To this:

```
$adminjail_data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As fatchAll will return an array of all the results from your query and then in your html page do this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">   
    <tr>        
        <th>Admin neve:</th>    
        <th>Indok:</th>     
        <th>Perc:</th>      
        <th>Időpont:</th>   
    </tr>  
  <?php foreach($adminjail_data as $row) :?>     
    <tr>        
        <th><?=$row["jailed_admin"];?></th>      
        <th><?=$row["jailed_reason"];?></th>
        <th><?=$row["jailed_ido"];?></th>
        <th><?=$row["jailed_idopont"];?></th>
     </tr>           
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

This is from PHP.net documentation about fetchAll:

```
PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows
```

You can refer to the full php documentation about PDOs fetchAll here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to list all the rows by iterating through the `$adminjail_data` array:

```
<table class="table table-hover">   
        <tr>        
            <th>Admin neve:</th>    
            <th>Indok:</th>     
            <th>Perc:</th>      
            <th>Időpont:</th>   
        </tr>  
<?php foreach($adminjail_data as $row) :?>     
        <tr>        
            <th><?=$row["jailed_admin"];?></th>      
            <th><?=$row["jailed_reason"];?></th>
            <th><?=$row["jailed_ido"];?></th>
            <th><?=$row["jailed_idopont"];?></th>

        </tr>           
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it not works :/ 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'jailed_admin' in /settings.php on line 102
1  
Warning: Illegal string offset 'jailed_reason' in /settings.php on line 103
1  
Warning: Illegal string offset 'jailed_ido' in/settings.php on line 104
1  
Warning: Illegal string offset 'jailed_idopont' in /settings.php on line 105
1

Comment: can u provide the format of $adminjail_data by var_dump the resultset;